# How can I set up a database on a localhost server?

Tags: android, database, web, server, localhost

I am developing an app for android which needs to connect to a database. For development purposes, I want to set it up on my local computer(Mac OSX El Capitan), I have already set up the localhost web server, I just don't know how to add a database to it, and access the elements through a web layer.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want a database server also. You could use [XAMPP](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html) for the webserver and the database server. Then you could use PHP to access the database and display the values on the website

Comment: i set up the database using mysql, how do I now set up the web server using php? I can't seem to find a good tutorial online.

Comment: W3schools has a pretty good explanation: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: I found this 2 part video, is this method secure? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TM1Suk7sLbc